# df.replace showing error without formating the to_replace with str

Tags: python, pandas, string

I was trying to remove all the symbols from my wordlist for which I made a pandas dataframe 'df'. I know there are easier ways, but I wanted to try my way, where I listed the unique characters in a np.array first and then using for loop I separated only the special characters from the alphabet and put those special characters into another np.array.
My symbol array

```
symbols= 
[['!']
 ['&']
 ["'"]
 ['(']
 [')']
 [',']
 ['-']
 ['.']
 ['1']
 ['2']
 ['3']
 [':']
 [';']
 ['?']
 ['[']
 [']']]
```

Now, I ran a for loop for each of the item in the symbol array and replaced that with space using df.replace (Before that I added an empty space before all the symbols and created symbolspace, to avoid error with replacing '(')

```
for symbol in symbolspace:
    df=df.str.replace(str(symbol),"", regex= True)
```

Now my question is, it did the job correctly except for the '-'. But at first I tried this with `df.replace(symbol,"", regex= True)` instead of `df.replace(str(symbol),"", regex= True)`  and that gave me this `error:  missing ), unterminated subpattern`. Please answer why am I getting this error. All the entries of that array symbolspace are already strings (it shows str64) even if I don't use `str(symbol)`. And why did it not work for '-' from the symbol np.array? It works when i write only `df.replace('-',"",regex=True)`

Answer (score 1):

> But at first I tried this with `df.replace(symbol, "", regex= True)` that gave me this `error:  missing ), unterminated subpattern.`

In this case, `symbol` is a list like `['(']`. So  [`pandas.DataFrame.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) will replace elements in list with `""`.

The reason why you get error is because you enable `regex`, and `(` is a special character in regex. It should be well enclosed by `)`.

> why did it not work for '-' from the symbol `np.array`?

When you do `str(symbol)`, the list is converted to string like `['-']`. Since you enable regex mode with `regex=True`, things in `[]` will be treated as a set of characters you wish to match. `-` in square brackets is treated as special character. Say you write `[a-c]`, it is the same with is the same as `[abc]`.